# Object reference exactly

Tags: object, language-agnostic, reference

```
Demo demo=new Demo();
```

Here demo is a reference variable. Are reference variables equal to object references... ?

If no then please explain the concept of object reference.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I am implementing this in JAVA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `Demo` represents the *type* of the object.
- `demo` represents the object reference, you will be able to refer to `new Demo()` object and calling its methods (for example).
- `new Demo()` represents the object itself which is situated in heap memory.

Comment: A reference variable can also be named as object reference.. ?

Comment: Honestly in java language I have used so far only the term of object reference. Which is the language you are associating the first term with ?

Answer (score 1):

In case of java language,
When you write the statement

```
Demo obj = new Demo();
```

It means that You are declaring a variable named obj and it is of type Demo.
by writing

obj = new Demo();

You are creating a new object in the heap memory and the reference variable "obj" will refer to it so that when you want to access the object created just now, you can access it through reference variable "obj".

so when you want to call some method on Demo object, you can call it using

```
obj.someMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

**A reference to an object is a way to denote that object**. The address of an object, for example, is one kind of reference (probably the simplest kind). Other kinds of references can exist, too, and they are written and read using some more complicated logic. It could theoretically be a double pointer, a pseudo-address, or something else - as long as it contains enough information that (if interpreted in a specified way) can be used to denote a specific object, .

**A reference variable is a variable whose *value* is a *reference to an object*.** So, for example, a reference variable could be a variable whose value is the address of an object, or (as I described above) something different, but equivalent.

For comparison, **the other common type** of variable (called *primitive type* in Java, *value type* in C# and other names in other contexts) **is the kind variable whose value is an actual object** (instead of a reference).